Adjusting frontend to access backend post-public deployment?
I have a frontend and backend application currently running on a local server. Now, I want to deploy them publicly. Considering that my frontend consumes data from my backend via the address localhost:3000, I'm wondering if I need to make modifications to the frontend services so they can still access the backend once the frontend is deployed publicly. Additionally, the backend and frontend will be on the same server during deployment
Ensure frontend-backend connectivity post-public deployment on the same server, given frontend currently accesses backend via localhost:3000?
